# Is there a simpler way to remember the sequence in which we can use pipe function in R programming?

Tags: r, tidyverse

It often takes me wrong while using pipe (%>%) function in R with dplyr or tidyverse packages. Is there a simpler way to remember in which we can order %>% function.

Example: on what basis we used sequence of filter, group_by, summarise & arrange functions here :

```
mtcars %>%
        filter(carb > 1) %>%
        group_by(cyl) %>%
        summarise(Avg_mpg = mean(mpg)) %>%
        arrange(desc(Avg_mpg))
```

As there is a sequence in SQL server like SELECT, FROM, WHERE, GROUP BY, HAVING, ORDER BY

Is there a simpler way to remember the sequence in which we can use %>% function?

Comment: I don't think there is anything to remember here. It completely depends on what you want to do and in which order.

Comment: As there is a sequence in SQL server like SELECT, FROM, WHERE, GROUP BY, HAVING, ORDER BY. I just wanted to know is there something here too?

Comment: Hey Vin, the comparison to SQL would have to be different. Every `dplyr`function outputs a `dataframe`(or `tibble` to be exact). The analogy therefore would be in SQL 'In what order do subqueries have to be?' - which also does not make sense.

Answer (score 1):

There is no set order because you can put these commands in any order or sequence depending on what it is that you want to do.

Observe:

```
mtcars %>%
group_by(cyl) %>%
summarise(Avg_mpg = mean(mpg), Avg_carb = mean(carb)) %>%
filter(Avg_carb > 1) %>%
arrange(desc(Avg_mpg))
```

Is equally as valid as your code example but does of course something very different.

You have to understand that the `%>%` pipe is actually irrelevant here! The pipe simply simplifies your syntax by omitting the dataset in each function-call.

`filter`, `arrange`, `mutate`, etc. can be chained however you like and do not have to follow a specific pattern.

`group_by()` and `summarise()` are somewhat different in that it makes mostly sense to first group and then summarise but you can chain another grouping directly after a summarise-call or summarise without first grouping.

Again a pipe is no sequencing tool it  merely does this:

```
# without pipe

filter(mtcars, carb > 1)

# with pipe

mtcars %>%
filter(carb > 1)


# without pipe

arrange(filter(mtcars, carb > 1),mpg)


# with pipe

mtcars %>%
filter(mtcars, carb > 1) %>%
arrange(mpg)
```

A pipe simply saves the dataframe resulting from your operation and pushes it into the next operation.

Comment: Thanks @Fnguyen this explanation cleared my doubt :)